# Data from online MySQL database with node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am building a ***nodejs SMS app***. This app will be sourcing data( the phone numbers) that are in the MySQL database of another website I own in cPanel (eg. ***example.org***) in a field called **phone** and the values also **phone**. This is what I have so far but am getting an error. Kindly help stating any possible cause of the error below. I am a beginner doing my first project which I will be hosting in heroku.

```js
var express  = require("express");
var mysql = require("mysql");
var app = express();

//Establishing connection
var con = mysql.createConnection({
 host:"example.org",
 user:"example_admin",
 password:"*********",
 database:"example_registerdb"
});

//Fetching the phone numbers from the phone column
con.connect(function(err){
 if(err) throw err;
 con.query("SELECT phone FROM phone", function(err, results, fields){
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log(results);
 });
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.send('Hello World');
});

var server = app.listen(3306, function(){
 console.log('Listening on port 3306');
});
```

Here is the error I am getting in cmd:

```
E:\Documents\Computer and Coding\PlayGround\PROJECTS\SMSAPI\index.js:15
        if(err) throw err;
                ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleConnectTimeout (E:\Documents\Computer and Coding\PlayGround\PROJECTS\SMSAPI\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:419:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:420:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (E:\Documents\Computer and Coding\PlayGround\PROJECTS\SMSAPI\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:145:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (E:\Documents\Computer and Coding\PlayGround\PROJECTS\SMSAPI\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:52:23)
    at Connection.connect (E:\Documents\Computer and Coding\PlayGround\PROJECTS\SMSAPI\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Documents\Computer and Coding\PlayGround\PROJECTS\SMSAPI\index.js:14:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
```

Comment: Please do not post questions with titles in all caps. It will only draw negative attention to your question.

Comment: Have you connected to the mysql server with any client other than this? I am going to wager a guess that port 3306 (the default mysql port), or whatever port mysql is listening on, is not freely exposed over the internet.

Comment: @rmlan now that it's not exposed freely, what's the way forward?

Comment: You haven't updated your question. My comment was only a guess. Have you confirmed that the port is not exposed? Who owns this MySQL server? If you don't own it and the port is not exposed, you don't really have _any_ way forward if you still want to connect directly to the server.

Comment: It belongs to my PHP website in cPanel. Then I have tried port 3306 and still same error. Kindly expound more on the port issue....